# Trigger jQuery function on window resize

Tags: jquery, resize, window, width

I would like to trigger a function when browser window is less-than/more-than 960px of width.
I have written some code witch looks like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 960) {

       dosomething();
    } else {         
       dosomething(); 
}
});
```

When re-sizing window width function is activated, but it keeps repeating function for every pixel is changed and it makes a lot of request witch I would like to avoid. Is there any way of activating function only once when it crosses 960px ?(and again, if screen is changed to more than 960 and lowered again, function is activated once again only once)

Thank you internet people if you know the answer!!!

---

I found the solution by setting timeout while changing window size:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function resizeStuff() {
     if ($(window).width() < 960)   
 {  
    loadCurrentPage();
} 
else  {
    loadCurrentPage();
}
}
 var TO = false;
 $(window).resize(function(){
 if(TO !== false)
clearTimeout(TO);
 TO = setTimeout(resizeStuff, 200); //200 is time in miliseconds
 });
```

Case closed. Again, proper search words in Google gave the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep that state in an variable and extend your if with it.

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var nextTrigger = 'below';
    if ($(window).width() < 960 && nextTrigger == 'below') {
        nextTrigger = 'above';
        dosomething();
    } else if(nextTrigger == 'above') {
        nextTrigger = 'below';
        dosomething(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: So basically declare a variable inside the event handler, and then on the next line check that variable? How does nextTrigger ever return anything else than `below` ?